# HTML from email cross site scripting issues

Tags: html, node.js, email, exchange-server, xss

I have a nodejs app that queries an Exchange server using Exchange Web Services. I retrieve emails out of an inbox and convert them to tasks in my app. However the body of the emails contains outlook formatted HTML. I would like to display the emails as closely to the original format as possible, with formatting/etc,  but I'm worried about cross site script being embedded in the emails. What is the best way to handle this? Are there any javascript or node libraries that can remove malicious cross site code in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Cheerio](https://npmjs.org/package/cheerio) to be the best way to accomplish this task. Once installed into Node I can then use the jQuery text function to convert the email body to text:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load(emailBody);

var emailText = $('body').text();
```

Then you can install [markdown](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) to parse the plain text back to safe html in markdown styling:

```
var markdown = require( "markdown" ).markdown;
console.log( markdown.toHTML( emailText ) );
```

Then if you want to display the email in original format you can save the original format in your database and give users an option to display it if they dare. Of course that opens up opportunity for cross site scripting again, but if you only give the option to trusted users then you will probably be safe. Maybe you could also give them the option to download the original source and run it on their local machine, so it's not executing on your server.